# Relation with Schrodinger equation?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

i have this equation :

$$-\varepsilon^2\Delta u+V(x) u= h(x) f(u)$$ 
can i consider it as a Schrodinger equation:

$$ i\varepsilon \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}=-\varepsilon^2\Delta \Psi+(V(x)+E)\Psi-|\Psi|^{q-2}\Psi,~x\in \mathbb{R}^N$$
$$\Psi(t,x)=\exp(\frac{-iET}{\varepsilon})u(x), ~u:\mathbb{R}^N\to[0,+\infty)$$

What is $h(x) f(u)$ in this case please ? ($h,f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ continuous )

Comment: What is $f(u)$? If it's not a linear function, your equation is nonlinear. You are considering a nonlinear Schrodinger equation in relation, but it is a very specific equation with a specific nonlinear part, while your function $f(u)$ is general so far

Comment: Adding some context (i.e. where you encountered the initial equation) might help to get some kind of answer

Comment: @YuriyS i mean is the equation with h and f , is more general than the given Schrodinger equation

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar i found it like it is writen

Comment: I'm almost sure the Schrodinger Equation has **Hermitian Operators** (2nd derivatives), I provided a link that you can refer to, for more information. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrödinger_equation
. Anyway, I hope you get your answer ASAP.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar, re: your first comment. Don't both notations mean the same operator? (Laplace operator)

Comment: @YuriyS Yes, I made a pretty hasty conclusion. You are right. Thank you.

Comment: @Vrouvrou Just to clarify, are you asking what $h(x)f(u)$ are if you decide to set $\Psi(t,x) = \exp(-\frac{iEt}{\varepsilon})u(x)$ in the given Schrodinger equation?

Comment: Please clarify the question. Again, the $|\Psi|^{q-2}\Psi$ term doesn't correspond to $h(x)f(u)$ unless both functions have very specific form. What do you really want to do and why are you trying to write your equation as Schrodinger equation?

Comment: Yes @bames that's what i want to do

Comment: @YuriyS i found it in a thesi , but i dont know how to prove it

Comment: @Vrouvrou, give a link to the thesis please. Also, it's still not clear what exactly are you trying to prove?

Comment: i have it in pdf version writen in portuguese@YuriyS